# Can not split the IP address and port using "strtok" where input is in Char *

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying so break IP into two parts but it's not working.
can anyone point out the Problem

```
    void encode_ip_with_port(unsigned char *tlvbuf) {
    // 100.100.100.100:65000
    // abcd:abcd:abcd:abcd:abcd:abcd:abcd:abcd:12344
        // Ipv4
        struct in_addr addr;
        // Remove Port
        char *ipv4 = NULL ;
        char *port = NULL;
        printf("Input : %s\n ",tlvbuf);
        char input = ":";
        //char str[]="this, by the way, is a 'sample'";
        ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, &input);
        port = strtok(NULL, ":");
        printf("Ipv4 : %s\n",ipv4);
                printf("port : %s\n",port);
        if (!inet_pton(AF_INET,ipv4 , &addr)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not convert address\n");
        }
}
```

Here `ipv4` is printing `ipv4 : 100.100.100.100:65000`
it should print `100.100.100.100`

Comment: typo `char input = ":";` --> `char *input = ":";`, `ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, &input);` --> `ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, input);`

Comment: even if i enter `ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, ":");` it's not working.

Comment: `ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, ":");` it's working.

Comment: i tried it `ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, ":");`

Comment: I think you may be missing the prototype: `#include<string.h>`.

Comment: @Merom [DEMO](http://ideone.com/1YWllx) Probably cause that does not work is in the other part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok` expects a string as input. You need to change the following:

Add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Change:

```
    char *input = ":";  // char --> char*
    ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, input);  // removed &
```

Working example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    char *ipv4, *port;
    char tlvbuf[80] = "100.100.20.1:65000";
    char* input = ":";
    ipv4 = strtok(tlvbuf, input);
    port = strtok(NULL, ":");
    printf("Ipv4 : %s\n",ipv4);
    printf("port : %s\n",port);
}
```

Output:

> Ipv4 : 100.100.20.1
>
> port : 65000

Comment: But if i say i have Character stream rather than character array ? then ?
Do i have to convert it to character array ? is it possible to apply it in character stream ?

Comment: You need to read it from the stream and put it in a character array first. Don't forget to null-terminate the array if the function you use to read from the stream doesn't do it for you.

Comment: This is the solution i can see only Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char a[30] = "100.100.100.100:2500";
char *p = NULL;
p = strtok(a,":");

printf("%s\n",p);

p = strtok(NULL,":");
printf("%s\n",p);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your 2. `p = strtok(a,":");` should be `p = strtok(NULL,":");`

Comment: @Gopi , Copy paste your entire program and you'll see what's wrong. Or else compare the program in codepad and your program

Comment: @CoolGuy copy pasted the whole code what is wrong in it?

Comment: Are you sure? The problem is `main{...}` --> `int main(){...return 0;}`

Comment: @CoolGuy Yeah I guessed you might be mentioning that :) Was wondering what is wrong with the logic

Comment: @CoolGuy There you have it :)